# Recommendations for log analysis tools for ejabberd logs

Tags: data-mining, ejabberd, log-analysis

I'm looking at a massive set of ejabberd logs, and I'm trying to pry out some useful information from them. Are there any existing tools that can help me get some of the work done, or am I left to roll my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the type of information you are looking in the logs ?
For ejabberd platform analysis, there is an ejabberd monitoring solution called TeamLeader ( http://www.process-one.net/en/solutions/teamleader/ ) but this might be overkill.

Comment: It does solve my problem, and it is also, overkill :)

Comment: ok, let me know if you have basic needs, so that I could suggest simpler approach (if it does exist).

Comment: @Mickaël teamleader is opensource tools else its commercial tool for ejabberd monitoring.